# timestamp problem once loaded the field are 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mariadb

my CSV file is

```
dc,HostID,HostMBReads,HostMBWrites,Reads,Writes,MBs,ReadResponseTime,WriteResponseTime,ResponseTime,SyscallCount,HostIOs,time
300000000252,lac01_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.38602328,0.0,2019-03-27 18:50:00
300000000252,lac03_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.81333333,0.0,2019-03-27 18:55:00
300000000252,lac04_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.40666667,0.0,2019-03-27 19:00:00
300000000252,lac05_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.4342762,0.0,2019-03-27 19:05:00
300000000252,solace_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2019-03-27 18:50:00
300000000252,solace1_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2019-03-27 18:55:00
300000000252,solace2_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2019-03-27 19:00:00
300000000252,solace3_ig,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2019-03-27 19:05:00
```

i created the table with this :

```
CREATE TABLE `host_metrics` (

   `dc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `HostID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `HostMBReads` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `HostMBWrites` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `Reads` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `Writes` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `MBs` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `ReadResponseTime` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `WriteResponseTime` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `ResponseTime` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `SyscallCount` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `HostIOs` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
   `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (dc,HostID,time));
```

i load the data with this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/max/GLOBAL_Host_metrics.csv' INTO TABLE host_metrics FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (dc, HostID, HostMBReads, HostMBWrites, `Reads`, Writes, MBs, ReadResponseTime, ResponseTime, SyscallCount, HostIOs, time);
```

the problem the select show me the time at 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for all the hosts

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra column in the data, or a missing column name from the list.